# How can I remote debug a Python script running on Linux from Windows using PyScripter?

Tags: python, debugging, remote-debugging, pyscripter

I have a Python script (running Python v2.6 or v2.7) that runs on Linux and also AIX.

I'd like to be able to debug this script from Windows.  I'd like to use PyScripter if possible.

If it is not possible to use PyScripter, what other combination of IDE + debugger would you recommend?  I would prefer something easy to set up and get running quickly without a huge amount of tinkering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to debug a script on a remote machine from PyScripter.  This is a planned feature thought.  You may be able to use winpdb.

**Update:**  PyScripter 3.5 supports running/debugging scripts running remotely at Linux and Windows machines.  Please have a look at this [blog post](https://pyscripter.blogspot.com/2018/10/new-feature-run-and-debug-files-on.html) for details. Have a look also at this [blog post](https://pyscripter.blogspot.com/2018/10/working-with-remote-files-preview-of.html).

Comment: Thanks!  Any ideas on how to set up winpdb?

Comment: I got this working today - I debugged a script running on AIX (IBM's Unix) from WinPDB running on Windows.  Yay!  It required a small script modification but was easy to do.  The link is here: http://winpdb.org/docs/embedded-debugging/  Note that rpdb2 is not a part of standard python and will need to be installed separately.  You can place rpdb2.py in the same directory as your script and it should work.